# Angular 5: HTTP post `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400.`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-headers

I have the following service; no matter how much I configure it I cannot get the http request to work.

**Chrome Console Error**
`Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400.`
[image]

**My Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';



@Injectable()
export class SlackService {
    extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }
    handleError (error: Response | any) {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

    private url: string = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxx/xxx';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    public slack(data: any): Observable<{}> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let headers: Headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

}
```

I remember having this problem in AngularJS and the following fixed it... What is the equivalent in angular 2+?

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
});
```

Ive seen answers like this [Angular 2 Token: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881964/angular-2-token-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-400) but hasnt helped

**this worked in PostMan**

```
curl -X POST \
  https://hooks.slack.com/services/xx/xx/xx \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d payload=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22channel%22%3A%20%22%23general%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22username%22%3A%20%22webhookbot%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22This%20is%20posted%20to%20%23general%20and%20comes%20from%20a%20bot%20named%20webhookbot.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22icon_emoji%22%3A%20%22%3Aghost%3A%22%0A%20%20%20%7D
```

Comment: maybe look at slacks api docs to see which headers are required to make the call.

Comment: @floor I edited the question to include a snippet of what is working now

Answer (score 0):

It seems your payload must be param instead of json
Try this, if you have jQuery

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
declare var $: any


@Injectable()
export class SlackService {
    extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }
    handleError (error: Response | any) {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

    private url: string = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxx/xxx';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    public slack(data: any): Observable<{}> {
        let body = $.param(data);
        let headers: Headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

}
```

Or try the new HttpClient soon the old htpp library will be deprecated see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/37797e2)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';



@Injectable()
export class SlackService {

    handleError (error: Response | any) {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

    private url: string = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxx/xxx';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public slack(data: any): Observable<{}> {
        const requestOptions = {
            params: new HttpParams()
        };
        //Add all your payload here
        requestOptions.params.set('foo', 'bar');


        return this.http.post(this.url, requestOptions , {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;' })
        })
       .map((res) => res.json())
       .catch(this.handleError);
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesnt work... There is no variation that rids me of the error `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400`...

Answer (score 0):

For me looks like API is missing CORS configuration (**OPTIONS** http method).

Modern web browsers make requests for **OPTIONS** (pre-flight) first if origin is different.

Basically what you need to do is configure CORS at your backend - frontend have nothing to do with it.

More about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: I am trying to make this call to Slack from the frontend... It works on other webprojects. This is an Angular HTTP module task. I must be miss using it some how

Answer (score -1):

try changing the following line of code:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

to

```
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Comment: That doesnt change the outcome